# Connected Sum and Special Holonomy

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Are there any contexts in which we can say with certainity that the connected sum of two special holonomy manifolds (eg Kahler, Calabi-Yau, G2...) has the same holonomy group? I would also be interested in such results for weaker structures such as complex structures or torsion-free G-Structures

Comment: How are you doing the connected sum in the Riemannian (or hermitian) category?  Topologically, it's well-defined, but ...

Comment: I was referring to the riemannian category, although I know there is not a canonical way to do the connected sum in that case. I was just wondering if there has been any work done considering connected sums of special holonomy manifolds in any sense